# CircleProgressIndicator with round caps

Tags: flutter

CircularProgressIndicator does not seem to support alternative types of stroke end caps. How can I achieve an intermediate indicator with round caps.

I know that https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator supports custom end caps, if all fails I can have a constantly rotating percent indicator with animated percent changes.